# Allowing formula inserted via VBA to adapt to row numbering

Tags: vba, excel

How do you allow the forumla that you have inserted via VBA to adapt to the row numbering (i.e. formula inserted at row 50000 using code below will become GCDnm(D5000,E5000) instead of GCDnm(D6,E6)?

Column B is the main column where information gets added continually. Column J and K are all filled by formulas from the code below.

```
Sub macro2()


Dim lastrow, lastrowJ, lastrowK As Long


lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lastrowJ = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
lastrowK = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

Range("J" & lastrowJ + 1 & ":J" & lastrow).Formula = "GCDnm(D6,E6)"
Range("K" & lastrowK + 1 & ":K" & lastrow).Formula = "LOOKUP(....)"

End Sub
```

So instead, I would like it to be something like

```
Range("J" & lastrowJ + 1 & ":J" & lastrow).Formula = "GCDnm(Dcurrentrow,Ecurrentrow)"
Range("K" & lastrowK + 1 & ":K" & lastrow).Formula = "LOOKUP(....)"
```

for current row is the row at which the formula is being pasted.

Comment: Instead of adding the formula one by one as values gets added in B dynamically, just determine the new range to fill in the formula and reapply in it. See my post for a simple explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First approach**, is to use Resize:

```
Range("J" & lastrowJ + 1).Resize(lastrow - lastrowJ - 1).Formula = _
    "=GCDnm(D" & lastrowJ + 1 & ",E" & lastrowJ + 1 & ")"
Range("K" & lastrowK + 1).Resize(lastrow - lastrowK - 1).Formula = _ 
    "=LOOKUP(D" & lastrowK + 1 & ",...)"
```

instead

```
Range("J" & lastrowJ + 1 & ":J" & lastrow).Formula = "GCDnm(D6,E6)"
Range("K" & lastrowK + 1 & ":K" & lastrow).Formula = "LOOKUP(....)"
```

**Next approach** is to use AutoFill (you need to set formulas only in lines `lastrowJ + 1` for column `J` and `lastrowK + 1` for column `K`, and stretch them down):

```
Range("J" & lastrowJ + 1).Formula = _
    "=GCDnm(D" & lastrowJ + 1 & ",E" & lastrowJ + 1 & ")"
Range("K" & lastrowK + 1).Formula = _ 
    "=LOOKUP(D" & lastrowK + 1 & ",...)"

Range("J" & lastrowJ + 1).AutoFill _ 
    Destination:=Range("J" & lastrowJ + 1 & ":J" & lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("K" & lastrowK + 1).AutoFill _ 
    Destination:=Range("K" & lastrowK + 1 & ":K" & lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

**Or another way**. If you know that you have *relative* formulas (without $ sign) in `J6` and `K6` (in example `=GCDnm(D6,E6)`) than you can use this approach:

```
Range("J6").Copy
Range("J" & lastrowJ + 1 & ":J" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

Range("K6").Copy
Range("K" & lastrowK + 1 & ":K" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

That is automatic in vba. For example you want to enter formula in column c with sum of a and b like this:

```
Range("C1").Formula = "A1+B1"
```

And values in A and B is dynamic so you get the last row.

```
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("C1:C" & lrow).Formula = "A1+B1"
```

Above code will result to sum of Ax+Bx where x is the corresponding row of C.
So no need to worry about it. Just identify the range you want the formula in.
Then supply the formula for the first set of rows only like above and it is good to go.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a formula that is location aware, use the R1C1 format of the formula

so your formula that is (I assume) in J6, which is currently

```
=GCDnm(D6,E6)
```

becomes

```
=GCDnm(RC[-6],RC[-5])
```

and will work in any J cell - Excel will then display it as the appropriate *GCDnm()* formula.
if you want to find out what the R1C1 formula is without having to change the options, you can print (**?**) the value in the immediate window:

> ?[j6].formula
>   =GCDnm(D6,E6)
>   ?[j6].formular1c1
>   =GCDnm(RC[-6],RC[-5])